# Trouble getting Tomcat to start up during install

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, path

I installed Java and now added Tomcat.  I configured Tomcat, but it is not running.

What I did was add the line:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
```

as the first non-comment line in the /home/myuser directory. And then I went to the /opt/tomcat/bin directory and ran this command:

```
./startup.sh
```

and it said command was not found.  Any reason for that?  I see the startup.sh script right in that directory when I do an ls command.  I use Ubuntu by the way.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Can you post the tomcat log or copy/paste the startup output?  It might not be startup,sh that can't be found but maybe the path to your shell in the first line in the script is bad?

Comment: try `. ./startup.sh` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I would do is type `echo $JAVA_HOME` as the user that is starting tomcat. Second, it seems you are using the JVM, you need to **use the JDK** instead. Tomcat needs the tools in the JDK to run properly.

`startup.sh` actually calls `catalina.sh` which resides in the same directory. I've always added the variables that tomcat needs at the top of this file to make sure that it is *always* loaded with the java instance it needs for your app and that can't be accidentally changed by someone.

If you look at the top of `catalina.sh` it has all the variables you can set. The ones you would be most interested in are:

```
#   JAVA_HOME       Must point at your Java Development Kit installation.
#                   Required to run the with the "debug" or "javac" argument.
#
#   JRE_HOME        Must point at your Java Development Kit installation.
#                   Defaults to JAVA_HOME if empty.
```

Comment: @Zypher, This contradicts http://stackoverflow.com/a/16727162/632951 . Only JRE is needed unless you use `catalina debug`. Tomcat 5.5 and above has eclipse compiler inside it.