# startup.sh generates "Command not found" in Tomcat

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trouble getting Tomcat to start up during install](https://serverfault.com/questions/255700/trouble-getting-tomcat-to-start-up-during-install)

Hello,

I have a tomcat installation and a bunch of start/stop scripts in the bin directory as there should be.

When I navigate to the bin directory and try to run the startup.sh command, I just get  command not found:

```
$ startup.sh
startup.sh: command not found
```

but that is very strange because there is an executable file like that in the directory:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 lcolvin lcolvin 11944 2011-02-04 04:52 catalina.bat
-rwxrwxr-x 1 lcolvin lcolvin 18108 2011-02-04 04:52 catalina.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 lcolvin lcolvin  2495 2011-02-04 04:52 catalina-tasks.xml
-rwxrwxr-x 1 lcolvin lcolvin  1930 2011-02-04 04:52 configtest.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 lcolvin lcolvin  1307 2011-02-04 04:52 cpappend.bat
-rwxrwxr-x 1 lcolvin lcolvin  2055 2011-02-04 04:52 digest.bat
-rwxrwxr-x 1 lcolvin lcolvin  1624 2011-02-04 04:52 digest.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 lcolvin lcolvin  6259 2011-02-04 04:52 service.bat
-rwxrwxr-x 1 lcolvin lcolvin  3216 2011-02-04 04:52 setclasspath.bat
-rwxrwxr-x 1 lcolvin lcolvin  3991 2011-02-04 04:52 setclasspath.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 lcolvin lcolvin  2052 2011-02-04 04:52 shutdown.bat
-rwxrwxr-x 1 lcolvin lcolvin  1563 2011-02-04 04:52 shutdown.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 lcolvin lcolvin  2053 2011-02-04 04:52 startup.bat
-rwxrwxr-x 1 lcolvin lcolvin  1956 2011-02-04 04:52 startup.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 lcolvin lcolvin  3547 2011-02-04 04:52 tool-wrapper.bat
-rwxrwxr-x 1 lcolvin lcolvin  4666 2011-02-04 04:52 tool-wrapper.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 lcolvin lcolvin  2057 2011-02-04 04:52 version.bat
-rwxrwxr-x 1 lcolvin lcolvin  1567 2011-02-04 04:52 version.sh
```

Any idea why this would be happening? I am using Ubuntu.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @slillibri said, or put `bash`in front of it, making the command `bash startup.sh`. The file doesn't need to be executable then.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use ./startup.sh because the tomcat bin/ directory is probably not in your PATH.