# Tomcat running, catalina throwing exception 

Tags: tomcat

So I have to preface that I'm not familiar with tomcat/catalina, but trying to troubleshoot this anyway. Anyway I see in /var/log/tomcat5/catalina.out I'm seeing these errors:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat5
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat5
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat5/temp
Using JRE_HOME:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:223)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:410)
```

I'm not really sure what this means. This installation was working a week ago ... did something get corrupted? How would I figure if it did ... what other information would be valuable here?

Tomcat seems to be running and starting up fine ...

UPDATE: this might be related:

```
Jun 19, 2011 11:00:25 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-9080
Jun 19, 2011 11:00:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
log4j:ERROR LogMananger.repositorySelector was null likely due to error in class reloading, using NOPLoggerRepository.
```

Some more stuff in the logs:

```
2011-06-12 23:04:45,223 INFO [main] [com.atlassian.confluence.lifecycle] contextInitialized Starting Confluence 3.1.1 (build #1724)
2011-06-12 23:04:45,663 INFO [main] [beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from c
lass path resource [bootstrapContext.xml]
2011-06-12 23:04:46,134 INFO [main] [beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from c
lass path resource [setupContext.xml]
2011-06-12 23:04:46,236 INFO [main] [beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from c
lass path resource [bootstrapCacheContext.xml]
2011-06-12 23:04:47,571 INFO [main] [atlassian.plugin.manager.DefaultPluginManager] init Initialising the plugin system
2011-06-12 23:04:48,338 INFO [main] [atlassian.plugin.manager.DefaultPluginManager] init Plugin system started in 0:00:00.748
Jun 12, 2011 11:05:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
SEVERE: Catalina.stop: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:525)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:475)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:372)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:186)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:395)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:344)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:435)
Jun 12, 2011 11:05:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.pa
th: /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18/jre/lib/i386/client:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18/jre/lib/i386:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18/jre/../lib/i386:/usr/java/packag
es/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib
```

CLEAN LOG OUTPUT FROM STARTING TOMCAT:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat5
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat5
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat5/temp
Using JRE_HOME:       
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:223)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:410)
```

So I did a /etc/rc.d/init.d/tomcat status and I get this:

```
[wqadm1n@ip-72-167-51-178 proc]$ sudo /etc/rc.d/init.d/tomcat5 status
/etc/rc.d/init.d/tomcat5 is stopped
[wqadm1n@ip-72-167-51-178 proc]$ sudo /etc/rc.d/init.d/tomcat5 start
Starting tomcat5:                                          [  OK  ]
[wqadm1n@ip-72-167-51-178 proc]$ sudo /etc/rc.d/init.d/tomcat5 status
lock file found but no process running for pid 30774
```

Comment: Is this pertinent: Jun 19, 2011 11:00:25 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-9080
Jun 19, 2011 11:00:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
log4j:ERROR LogMananger.repositorySelector was null likely due to error in class reloading, using NOPLoggerRepository.

Comment: Maybe a clean log could help. Stop tomcat, verify tomcat is not running "ps aux |grep tomcat",rename catalina.out to something else, then start tomcat and post the log

Comment: added clean log output at bottom of message

Comment: If I start the process as root, is that ok? e.g. sudo /etc/rc.d/init.d/tomcat5 start?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a `JRE_HOME` directory set. You need to download the java SDK (yes, SDK) and point your JRE_HOME to the root of your SDK folder.

You need to set it in your init script or your `catalina.sh` (my preference has always been `catalina.sh`)

Also see my answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/255700/trouble-getting-tomcat-to-start-up-during-install/255728#255728)

My guess is that the init script is su'ing into a different user enviroment, so if you don't have it in your startup scripts it will never get properly set.

Comment: Any thoughts to how that could unset?

Comment: @mark see my edits.

Comment: So it looks like it's being set in the tomcat5.conf file, JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/latest", which is correct. Does that seem like a normal place for it to be set?

Comment: @Mark, IIRC that is a valid place, but the `/usr/java/latest` makes me think it's the JRE _NOT_ the JDK (see my link above)

Comment: I'm not sure if JDK == SDK but latest is a symlink, see below:lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   16 2010-02-19 16:03 default -> /usr/java/latest
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root 4096 2010-02-19 16:03 jdk1.6.0_18
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 2010-02-19 16:20 jre1.6.0_18
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   21 2010-02-19 16:03 latest -> /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18

Comment: Ill try editing the catalina.sh file like you suggest and see if that helps.

Comment: I tried editing it explicitly stting JRE_HOME to /usr/java/latest, which actually points at /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18, that didn't work, I tried also setting it to point at /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18/bin ...thoughts? I also set JAVA_HOME to /usr/java/latest

Comment: Hmm, it _might_ be that you need JDK 5 not 6

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Then I noticed that I have accidentally deleted lib folder from tomcat directory. The issue got resolved as "lib" back in place. May this help.

Comment: Hi, and welcome on board on SF. Please take a moment to read this: https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer